# Android bluetooth connection with heart rate monitor

Tags: android, bluetooth

I purchased a heart rate monitor bluetooth WTEK HS-2BT and now I want to implement an app to track all the information retrieved. I tried to read the sensor through this example that uses bluetooth health ([example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-cts-4.0_r1/samples/BluetoothHDP/src/com/example/bluetooth/health)) without success. Someone tell me would know what alternative should I use to communicate with the device (since I can't pair the device directly)? With bluetooth sockets? Thanks!

The android version is 4.4.2

Answer (score 2):

The bluetooth device you mentioned is a BLE device (Bluetooth low energy, aka Bluetooth Smart).

You need to find some BLE example. You can try this one, for example: http://www.slideshare.net/lancenanek/htc-ble-hrm

Also, take a look in the BLE tutorial from android developers: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Good lucky!